# С++. ofstream не записывает в файл

Tags: c++, fstream

Не записывает в файл. Может ли быть ошибка с правами доступа?если да, то как её решить?подскажите пожалуйста, try catch уже пробовала. В данном коде выводит SUCCESS, но записи в файле нет.

```
#include <iosream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    //string path = "C:\\c2\\f.txt";

    ifstream ain;

    ofstream aout("C:\\c2\\f.txt");


    aout.open("C:\\c2\\f.txt");

    if (aout.is_open()) {
        aout << "Privet";
        cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
        aout.close();
    }

    else cout << "NE OTKRILSYA";

    string str;
    while (!ain.eof())
    {
        ain >> str;
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а с чего вы записывете?  ain вообше не свзан ни с каким файлом, а aout инициализирован неправильно.

Comment: И зачем вы дважды открываете `aout`?

Comment: если пишу ofstream aout.open("C:\\c2\\f.txt"); - пишет error: expected initializer before '.' token

Comment: записываю с Sublime text 3. А в чем ошибка инициализации?

Comment: AR Hovsepyan: Спасибо за подсказку с инициализацией!!! Работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ain >> str;
```

тут ошибка, надо <<,а не >>

Comment: У `ifstream` нет оператора `<<`

Answer (score -1):

ofstream aout("C:\c2\f.txt");

aout.open("C:\c2\f.txt");

Ты создал файл, открыл его, после чего снова открыл этот же файл. Думаю, ошибка в строке open - удали ее

Comment: Этому вопросу 3 года. Уже открытый файл можно открывать повторно. Причем там даже есть проверка, что файл действительно открылся.